# Angular services don't store data

Tags: angular, service

I'm trying to do app with date filter. So here's my problem:\

I want to store data in my service but when i'm routing my array at service is resetting itself.

How can i keep data permanently at my service.

Here's my code:

task.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NewTaskPageComponent, ToDoTask } from './new-task-page/new-task-page.component';
import { task } from './app.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {
  tasks:ToDoTask[] = [];
  constructor() { 
  }
  addTask(task:ToDoTask){
    this.tasks.push(task);
  }
  getTasks():ToDoTask[]{
    return this.tasks;
  }

}
```

new-task-page.component.ts

```
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from '../task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-task-page',
  templateUrl: './new-task-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-task-page.component.sass'],
  providers: [TaskService]
})
export class NewTaskPageComponent implements OnInit {
  newTask ?: ToDoTask;
  constructor(private _taskService:TaskService){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  sendTask(task:string,date:string): void{
    this.newTask = new ToDoTask(task,date);
    this._taskService.addTask(this.newTask);
    console.log(this._taskService.getTasks());
  }

}
export class ToDoTask{
  task: string;
  date: string;
  constructor(task:string,date:string){
    this.task = task;
    this.date = date;
  }

}
```

Comment: can you replicate the same over stack blitz we will be able help faster.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/sunba33/angulartraining here is stackblitz replicate

Comment: You can use localstorage to persist data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your first statement that you want it to be permanent. Storing is service and retrieving in different component will work until tab reloads.

This answer right explains the approach. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68272978/2900893

What you need is storage to store your task and retrieve when/wherever you want.

```
localstorage.setItem('task_key', your_task); //  (key, value) value you need to be in string
```

Same way you can get task by

```
localstorage.getItem('task_key')  // This returns your_task which you stored earlier
```

You can use indexDB as well

This way your data will be stored permanent even you reload or restart browser.

Answer (score 3):

That behaviour you are having is because, on your component, you have this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-task-page',
  templateUrl: './new-task-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-task-page.component.sass'],
  providers: [TaskService] // ----> delete this, you don't need it
})
```

It should be like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-task-page',
  templateUrl: './new-task-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-task-page.component.sass']
})
```

Since you already have a `service` that is provided in root, you don't need to provide it again in your component.

The service is already available in your whole application and any component can share and have access to the same instance of this service.